# Accessing Value from Key via Change (onWrite)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to access the value of a key(node) from the firebase realtime database. I am using the onWrite trigger which passes the change paramters, which holds snapshot of the database before the trigger and after the trigger. Therefore with the after trigger's snapshot I wish to place the key of a node into a constant variable although when I try I recieve a TypeError.

> Type Error Bug:
>
> TypeError: change.after.ref.child(...).val is not a function
>       at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:13:64)`

Thus meaning that .val() cannot be used in the way I have tried to use it, although I cannot see any other information to see how to handle this.

Relevant Segment of Code:

```
'user-strict'
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase); // load the firebase-functions and firebase-admin modules, and initialize an admin app instance from which Realtime Database changes can be made.

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_type}/{sender_id}").onWrite((change, context) => {

    const user_id = context.params.user_id;
    const notification_type = context.params.notification_type;
    const sender_id = context.params.sender_id;

    //Check if the notification is still to be sent (true not false)
    const notficationValid = change.after.ref.child(sender_id).val();
    console.log(`Notification Valid: `, notficationValid);
```

I expected the notificationValid variable to hold the value of 'true'.

Firebase Database

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `.ref` in your code is not needed:

```
change.after.child(sender_id).val()
```

---

Calling `.ref` on a `DataSnapshot` gives you back a `DatabaseReference`, which doesn't have a `val()` method.